# Which one is more used: tomato or tomatoes / strawberry or strawberries?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

When asking "Do you like...?" or saying "I like or I don't like...", is it more idiomatic to put "tomato" or "strawberry" in the singular or in the plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Do you like tomatoes?" or "... strawberries?" refers to actual *tomatoes* and *strawberries* as items. "Do you like strawberry?" is more likely to refer to the *flavor* of strawberry; for example, in strawberry jam/jelly, strawberry pie, etc. Both forms are perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: I think in the question, "Do you like strawberry (tomato, ...etc)?", "strawberry" or "tomato" is actually being used as an adjective, as TypeIA says, to refer to strawberry jam or strawberry pie, ..." So the context would need to specify whether it was pie, or jam, or candy that was under discussion.  If that is not included in the context, you wouldn't ask, "Do you like strawberry?" as a random question. You would use the plural if there was no other context.